# Как обратиться к динамическому css селектору

Tags: css

Генерируется css идентификаторы. Просто добавляется порядковый номер,
например:

```
#id,
#id1,
#id2,
#id3,
```

Как в css обратиться к этим идентификатором, может есть что то типа этого?

```
#id[*]
{.....}
```

Comment: даже если есть, зачем лепить такие костыли? почему нельзя использовать просто класс?

Comment: `id` это такой же атрибут, поэтому можно применить [селектор атрибутов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), но большого смысла в этом нет, проще заменить id на класс, и прописать стиль классу

Comment: ок, пусть будут классы, например .classx, .classxx, .classxxx, где x - неизвестное число (класс должен быть уникален, чтобы стили не применялись к другим блокам), и что теперь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ресурс:](http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/attr5)

> Возможны варианты, когда стиль следует применить к тегу с определённым
>   атрибутом, когда частью его значения является некоторый текст. При
>   этом точно не известно, в каком месте значения включен данный текст —
>   в начале, середине или конце. В подобном случае следует использовать
>   конструкцию *=. Она определяет, что значение атрибута содержит
>   указанный текст.

```
[id*=id] {
  ...      
}
```

Пример:

```css
/* Для наглядности */
#id1 { background: #ccc; }

#id2 { background: #ddd; }

#id3 { background: #ccc; }

#id4 { background: #eee; }

#id5 { background: #333; }

/* Ко всем */
[id*=id] {
  height: 100px;  
}
```

```html
<div id="id1"></div>
<div id="id2"></div>
<div id="id3"></div>
<div id="id4"></div>
<div id="id5"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `div[id^="id"]`. Селектор выберет все `div`, у которых аттрибут `id` начинается с "`id`"

Comment: Символ * вместо ^ эквивалентен слову "содержит". Также можно опустить выборку самого елемента div если нет определенного типа элемента, который нужно получить.

Comment: `*` означает содержит в любом месте, а `^` - означает в начале слова, что в более соответствует формулировке вопроса. Поэтому я считаю этот ответ точнее